# Proving that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is not a simply connected space.

Tags: general-topology, circles, connectedness

I just want to check my proof as I have provided an alternate proof to one that is the book.

So first we a lemma if X is simply connected and A is it's rectract then A is simply connected.

Now given $X=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$ and assuming $X$ is simply connected, then $S^1$ should also be simply connected. However, this will imply that a degree 1 circle function is degree 0 which is a contradiction.

Simply proof. Maybe too simple and I am missing something.

If you can provide alternate proofs too that will be great.

Comment: If you already know that $S^1$ is not simply connected, then it's that easy, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Right.  I mean it is certainly well known that the circle $S^1$ is not simply connected.  Its fundamental group is $\Bbb Z$.